# How can I merge my local branch with my remote branch on my server?

Tags: git, remote-server

I want to merge my local branch with the branch on my server. On my local computer I navigate to my project folder and then type:

```
git remote add origin ssh://myuser@myhost:22/html/myproject
```

But I get the error message:

> external Repository origin already exists

So I tried to use another branch name:

```
git remote add testbranch ssh://myhost@myuser:22/html/myproject
```

and then

```
git push testbranch master
```

and then I get the error message:

> fatal: '/myproject' does not appear to be a git repository fatal:
> Could not read from Remote-Repository. Please ensure that the correct
> access permissions exist and the repository exists.

I checked /myproject with git status, it is a git repository. The permission rights of the folder are 775.

Comment: As a sidenote, it might be confusing to refer to remotes as branches. ("*I tried to use another branch name*" --> This is not a branch, but a remote)

Comment: ssh url is not correct: `user@host:port/path`. Port is 22, you can leave it out: `user@host:/path`

Comment: @eftshift0 sorry, type mistake. I updated my question

Comment: @RomainValeri's comment is _also_ relevant. Just in case, it's not the source of the problem but they way the OP set it up is not.... consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> external Repository origin already exists

Then the command to use would be:

```
git remote set-url origin ssh://myhost@myuser/html/myproject
```

But for that, you would need a [bare repository](https://www.saintsjd.com/2011/01/what-is-a-bare-git-repository/) in `/html/myproject`, which it is [probably not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1830712/6309).

[Initializing a bare repository, and adding a post-receive hook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68246767/6309) is usually the way to updtae `/html/myproject` content.

Comment: Does it have to be bare, I think it is a normal git repository?

Comment: I tested the command, I get the error `The authenticity of host '[myhost]:22 ([999.111.222.33]:2222)' can't be established.Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (coding/.ssh/known_hosts).`

Comment: @peace_love I have added links regarding bare repositories.

Comment: @peace_love Regarding the error message, check out https://stackoverflow.com/q/17668283/6309.